# Get distinct values of the PIVOT Column

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

> Msg 8156, Level 16, State 1, Line 30
>   The column '2016-03-31' was specified multiple times for 'Pvt2'.

```
SELECT 
@columns = COALESCE(@columns + ', ','')+ QUOTENAME(PERIOD_DATE) 
 FROM 
    imd_user_db.vw_ScorecardAll v left outer join ( select  StatusId, 
       ParentId, StatusName

   from imd_user_db.fxGetCompanyStatuses(@CompanyId)    

  ) as d
on v.STATUSID = d.StatusId inner join imd_user_db.Employee as e
on v.SELECTED_ITEM_VALUE = e.EmployeeId and v.CRITERIA_TYPE_ID = 
 @CriteriaTypeId
where (COMPANY_ID = @CompanyId) and
      (v.STATUSID in (40,338) or d.ParentId in (40,338)) and
     PERIOD_DATE between @StartDate and @EndDate
```

Here is my pivot section:

```
Pivot(

    max(FINAL_SCORE_AGREED) 
    FOR [PERIOD_DATE] IN (' + @columns + '))as Pvt2';
```

Comment: what is your input, expected output.

Comment: edit your question and post it in question section, that is more readable format.

Comment: do a `PRINT @columns` and inspect the value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do a `PRINT @columns` you should be able to see that date is duplicate

You can add a `GROUP BY PERIOD_DATE` to the `@columns` query to get distinct `PERIOD_DATE`

```
SELECT 
@columns = COALESCE(@columns + ', ','')+ QUOTENAME(PERIOD_DATE) 
 FROM 
    imd_user_db.vw_ScorecardAll v left outer join ( select  StatusId, 
       ParentId, StatusName

   from imd_user_db.fxGetCompanyStatuses(@CompanyId)    

  ) as d
on v.STATUSID = d.StatusId inner join imd_user_db.Employee as e
on v.SELECTED_ITEM_VALUE = e.EmployeeId and v.CRITERIA_TYPE_ID = 
 @CriteriaTypeId
where (COMPANY_ID = @CompanyId) and
      (v.STATUSID in (40,338) or d.ParentId in (40,338)) and
     PERIOD_DATE between @StartDate and @EndDate
GROUP BY PERIOD_DATE   -- << add this line
```